# Make Facetime ignore incoming calls in macOS

Tags: audio, notifications, facetime

Does anyone know of a way (hack or otherwise) to prevent incoming FaceTime and iPhone Continuity calls, other than disabling both entirely? I still want to make iPhone and FaceTime calls from my Mac.

FaceTime is ridiculously aggressive about incoming calls: It will not only steal your mouse and keyboard focus and tab you out of fullscreen programs, it will also lower your entire system volume and pause your music. This sucks because I get about 4 spam phone calls per day. I don't mind answering legitimate calls on my iPhone.

The focus-stealing problem is the biggest, and I'd settle just with fixing that. I've seen a question about that asked [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/5636ph/does_anyone_know_how_to_stop_phone_calls_from/) but with no answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried disabling notifications? Or at least turning them down?

Under **** → **System Preferences** → **Notifications** → **FaceTime**, *uncheck* `Play sound for notifications`, then change the **Alert Style** to `Banners`. Banners shouldn’t steal focus.

[image: FaceTime Notification Settings]

You could also enable **Do Not Disturb** while in fullscreen by <kbd>⌥ opt</kbd>-clicking the Notification Center icon at the far right of your system menu bar. Some apps do this automatically, while others observe the `When mirroring to TVs and projectors` setting under the *Turn on Do Not Disturb* header.

This is accessed by going into **** → **System Preferences** → **Notifications** → **Do Not Disturb**.

Comment: Huh, this seems like something I would have tried. I think it works and will update if I notice it's not doing what I want. Also, nice answer format.